# automapping 1:1 mvc unmapped members found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to use automapper to map between my entites db class and my view model. They have the same exact prop names but i get the error thrown saying unmapped members found.  From what I understand if you have 1:1 Relationship you do not have to do the manual mapping in the config file.  what am I missing here?

product class

```
public class product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int numberCds { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double weight { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public int stockAlert { get; set; }
    public string salesTax { get; set; }
    public string imgURL { get; set; }
    public string videoURL { get; set; }
    public int views { get; set; }
    public string instantDownload { get; set; }
    public string downloadLink { get; set; }
    public int active { get; set; }
    public string addedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime addedTime { get; set; }
    public string updatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime updatedTime { get; set; }
}
```

entites class

```
public partial class newProduct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> numberCds { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> weight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> stock { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> stockAlert { get; set; }
    public string salesTax { get; set; }
    public string imgURL { get; set; }
    public string videoURL { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> views { get; set; }
    public string instantDownload { get; set; }
    public string downloadLink { get; set; }
    public int active { get; set; }
    public string addedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> addedTime { get; set; }
    public string updatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> updatedTime { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping Config
        public static void RegisterMaps()
        {

```
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {

            config.CreateMap<product, newProduct>();
            config.CreateMap<newProduct, product>();

        });


    }
```

and the controller

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (StoreEntities db = new StoreEntities())
        {

            var results = (from p in db.newProducts select p).Where(a => a.active == 1);



            var products = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<product>(results);


            return View(products);
        }
```

Comment: Possibly because `newProduct` contains nullable properties where as `product` contains non-nullable properties for the equivalent name (`int` -> `int?` is safe, but `int?` -> `int` is not)

Comment: Thank's i tried making the nullable's match but it did not work